# An unlocked wallet is holding 100% of <PAIR> LP

Tags: pancakeswap, vulnerability, liquidity-provider

I'm in https://poocoin.app/ to follow some charts of a meme token and found this message in red "An unlocked wallet is holding 100% of  LP".

By following the link I ended in a PancakeSwap LP page of that pair with just 2 holders.

Is this token somehow vulnerable to any exploit until the owner lock it (whatever this means) ?

Comment: can u get your coin back if that kind of message appear ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the owner can rug pull(remove liquidity, steal everyone's investment, and make the token valueless) any time. That is why that prompt exists. Locks are commonly done on DxSale and Poocoin checks if the LP holder is a DxSale/unicrypt/something else contract.

Comment: Jeeez!! But is this a contract vulnerability? I mean ... can someone pull the owner's rug first? I'm trying to find a way to pay theses scammers in same coin. I'm already developed a portal that monitor the all fresh new Tokens contracts in BSC as soon someone deploy it. I don't know if I can post the link here but if you want to see it send me a PM

Comment: Uh. Just forgot there is no PM in S.E. ... well let me know somehow.

Comment: No, unlocked liquidity isn't a contract vulnerability and no, you can't rug pull the owner because they own all the liquidity in the pool and they have control.

Answer (score 2):

If it says: An unlocked wallet is holding 100% of the lp. This means that the owner of the token can at any time get his liquidity and devalue the token. Therefore, you need to block liquidity, for example, I do it on openlock.io